# MikTex in spyder

Tags: anaconda, latex, sympy, spyder, miktex

How do you get LaTex output on Spyder? I saw some other post recommending installing the *MikTex* package but I don't know how to use it.

I installed the *MikTex* package on Anaconda Spyder, but now how do I use it? I have:

```py
import sympy as sp
sp.init_printing()

x = sp.symbols('x')
integrate(x)
```

But nothing

Comment: I think you need to have the `pdflatex` command in your PATH. That means that after opening a system terminal (i.e. `cmd.exe`) you should be able to write `pdflatex` on it and have the command recognized by it.

Answer (score 3):

I had troubles getting Latex output to work in Spyder too, and I was able to hunt the bug down. At least for me, the Miktex installation delivered by the conda `miktex` package got confused about being a shared or a single-user installation, and consequently failed to install the necessary packages on-the-fly.

Here's my strategy:

1. Verify if you have the same problem by looking at the Miktex log files (on Windows, in your user's `AppData\Local\Miktex\2.9\miktex\log` directory); watch out for lines like 
   `installing package (...) triggered by (...)`, immediately followed by entries marked `FATAL` with the error message `Administrative mode cannot be enabled (makes no sense) because this is not a shared MiKTeX setup.`
2. If this is the same issue for you, start the Miktex console in the conda Miktex package; the location is `(Anaconda dir)\Library\miktex\texmfs\install\miktex\bin\miktex-console.exe`. (Trying to run the `_admin` version fails with a similar "Administrative mode" error message.)
3. In the console, go to "Packages", and manuall install the following packages: `standalone`, `varwidth` and `zhmetrics`

After these steps, Latex output worked for me. Note that these package installations are user-specific, so you'll have to repeat them for each user.